# How to use $expand API parameter with $select on list users API of Microsoft graph?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

We are using Microsoft Graph APIs ( `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/` ) to get all users from Azure Active Directory ( AAD ).
We get the basic user parameters as the response.
We don't get `manager`, `groups` & `roles` of the user in the list users API paged response. We need to call separate API for an individual user with his AAD `id` & get this additional information. We come across this [$expand](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters#expand-parameter) parameter in API documentation which states the following (emphasis mine):

> ***Note:*** Not all relationships and resources support the $expand query parameter. For example, you can expand the ***directReports, manager, and memberOf*** relationships on a user, but you cannot expand its events, messages, or photo relationships. Not all resources or relationships support using $select on expanded items.

This note clearly suggests we shall get `manager` & `memberOf` properties for the user. But when we tried this with `/users` API it throws bad requests.

Again we searched more in an article titled [Known issues with Microsoft Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/known-issues) it has the information about `$expand` as follows,

> ***$expand:***
>
> - No support for nextLink
> - No support for more than 1 level of expand
> - No support with extra parameters ($filter, $select)

What is the exact use of `$expand`? How do we get additional information like manager, roles & groups of the user in [List users API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http) so that we don't have to call separate APIs per user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below  APIs under the `/beta` version in Microsoft Graph are subject to change. Use of these APIs in production applications is not supported.

[$expand](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters#expand-parameter)-Normally, you can query either the properties of a resource or one of its relationships in a single request, but not both. You can use the $expand query string parameter to include the expanded resource or collection referenced by a single relationship (navigation property) in your results.

[Memberof](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/user?view=graph-rest-beta#relationships) gives the groups, directory roles and administrative units that the user is a member of.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users?$expand=memberof
```

To get manager details please use below query

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users?$expand=manager
```

Comment: Yeah, We figured that out :)